# why does not toggle work on click if the element has a class JS

Tags: javascript

I do animation of cards using css and js. It seems that almost everything worked out. I just can't figure out why `this.classList.toggle ('is-active');`
does not remove the class on the second click on the element. Help fix the error. What is the problem here. Why does `toggle` work like `add` in this situation? What's my mistake.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const cardsLst = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  for (let card of cardsLst) {
    card.addEventListener("click", function() {
      for (let card of cardsLst) {
        card.classList.remove('is-active');
      }
      this.classList.toggle('is-active');
    });

  }
})
```

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.33%);
  grid-auto-rows: 70vh;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card img {
  transition: 2s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.card .card__title {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card__text {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  font-size: 15px;
  transform: translate(0px, 70vh);
  transition: transform .5s ease 0s;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
}

.card:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  /* Увеличиваем масштаб */
}

.card.is-active .card__text {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: transform .5s ease .5s;
  top: 50%;
  /* 3 */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.card:after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 1.3s;
}

.card.is-active:after {
  width: max(100vh, 100vw);
  height: max(100vh, 100vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://d626yq9e83zk1.cloudfront.net/files/2017/12/26-770x425.jpg">
    <div class="card__title">Lorem </div>
    <div class="card__text">ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, nulla? </div>

  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://d626yq9e83zk1.cloudfront.net/files/2017/12/26-770x425.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="card__title">Lorem </div>
    <div class="card__text">ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, nulla? </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://d626yq9e83zk1.cloudfront.net/files/2017/12/26-770x425.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="card__title">Lorem </div>
    <div class="card__text">ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, nulla? </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have removed `is-active` from the card in the loop and then `toggle` will certainly add the class because `is-active`' has already been removed.

Comment: To make the code less confusing, you should use different iteration variables in the two loops.

Comment: To solve the problem, the inner loop should skip removing the class when `this == card`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is-active` has already been removed in the `for` loop. Hence `toggle` will add it back.

As a fix, skip removing the class in the `for` loop.

```
for (let card of cardsLst) {
  if(card === this) { continue; }
  card.classList.remove('is-active');
}
```